# Is there a way to sign in once and reuse that browser again without re signing in using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver

I am scraping a website which needs to login for scraping every time. is there a way to remain sign in a fix browser and i can access that browser every time the script is started?
or how can i use the browser on which i have signed in manually or programmatically?

i am running different scripts for different purposes like to perform search, or to get main content, but every script needs log in for new browser.

```
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
option.add_argument("--disable-notifications")  
option.add_argument("headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install() , options = option)
driver.get('https://www.amazon.com/')
```

Comment: You'd use pickle to save the sign in.

Comment: Here is a tutorial on how to reuse a browser session, it may help you: [link](https://tarunlalwani.com/post/reusing-existing-browser-session-selenium/)

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to use pickle? Iam currently logging in using   
`driver.get("url")
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_name("email")
inputElement.send_keys('email')  
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
inputElement.send_keys('pass') `

Comment: Secondly is it possible to use one browser to run multiple different scripts to avoid login everytime for each script.